# Dynamically uploading images in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, file, upload

How can I upload multiple individual images with HTML and Javascript? The code I have is based on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL but I want to have option to create multiple upload buttons and each upload button should upload an individual image independent of the other buttons.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
     <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" onclick = "addEntry()" >Add</a>
      <script>
            function addEntry() {
            var browse = document.createElement("INPUT");
            browse.setAttribute("type", "file");

            picture = document.createElement("img");
            picture.src = "";
            picture.setAttribute("alt", "No image chosen");
            picture.setAttribute("height","100");
            browse.setAttribute("onchange", "previewFile(picture)");
            document.body.appendChild(browse);
            document.body.appendChild(picture);
            }

            function previewFile(inPic){

            var preview = document.querySelector('img');
            var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; 
            var reader  = new FileReader();


            reader.onloadend = function () {
                preview.src = reader.result;
            }

            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
            } else {
                preview.src = "";
            }
            }
```

Comment: What is your specific problem with this code?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the querySelector part. Basically, when I  use the first upload button, it uploads and displays the image. When I upload with any of the other buttons, the file uploads but no image appears.

Comment: For visual reference: http://jsfiddle.net/3jdL8nu7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to use file readers.

if you dont have to support ancient browsers, use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

code snippet from there:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to string "123456"

// HTML file input user's choice...
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

// JavaScript file-like object...
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```